# Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio 2.0 is slower

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a multi-project (2 modules) of which building takes about 1/2 min each time. When I press Run in Android Studio, I have to wait every time to rebuild the app, which is extremely slow. It's took 6/8 min each time.

[image]

Is it possible to automate building process in Android Studio? Or do you have any advice on how to make this process faster?

here is my build.gradle file (app module):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {  url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'

    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'com.github.fenjuly:ArrowDownloadButton:9e15b85e8a'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:contextmenu:1.0.5'
        compile project(':locationlib')
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    compileOptions {

        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
        jumboMode true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

    }
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 22
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = []
            }
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'

        }
    }
   }
```

**My notebook spects are
I3 8GB RAM and Windows 10 64bits**

Actually I have Android Studio 2.0 preview 9
with this studio64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview2.0
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

And 
**The Gradle work is OFFLINE**

Comment: Is a normal time, in Android Studio 2.0 preview. Or update to preview7 and retest.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Android Studio 1.5.1** which is much faster than prior version of Android Studio.

Comment: They are trying 2.0 which is newer than 1.5.1

Comment: @FuriousGeorge Oppps Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

The 47deg maven repository is really slow. 
Your best alternative is finding a way to solve the dependencies provided by them elsewhere and removing this line from your repositories body:

```
maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
```

The build time will shorten noticeably.